# Nodemailer application sends email on page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, nodemailer

Building a simple form to allow users to send me an email. The form properly sends the email on submit. However, I also receive an email when the page is refreshed on my browser. What gives? I'm not sure if the issue is in my `server.js` file or the `index.ejs`. Is the `submit` button being triggered somehow on the page load?

Here's the `server.js` file:

```
var express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    nodeMailer = require('nodemailer'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    var app = express();
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.use(express.static(__dirname));
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    var port = 3000;
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
      res.render('index');
    });
    app.post('/contact', function (req, res) {
      let transporter = nodeMailer.createTransport({
          host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
          port: 465,
          secure: true,
          auth: {
              user: '****@gmail.com',
              pass: '****'
          }
      });
      let mailOptions = {
          from: req.body.name + ' &lt;' + req.body.email + '&gt;', // sender address
          to: '****@gmail.com', // list of receivers
          subject: 'New message test', // Subject line
          text: `${req.body.name} (${req.body.email}) says: ${req.body.message}`, // plain text body
          html: '<b>Email Test</b>' // html body
      };

      transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
          if (error) {
              return console.log(error);
          }
          console.log('Message %s sent: %s', info.messageId, info.response);
              res.render('index');
          });
      });
          app.listen(port, function(){
            console.log('Server is running at port: ',port);
          });
```

And the index.ejs:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

</head>

<body>
  <form action="/contact" id="contact-form" method="post" role="form">
    <fieldset>
      <label for="name">Name &#42;</label>
      <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name" required="required">
      <label for="email">Email &#42;</label>
      <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Your email" required="required">
      <label for="message">Message &#42;</label>
      <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Enter your message here" rows="3" required="required"></textarea>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you open the route / it send the email straight away?

Comment: Yes. Refreshing the page I get an `Are you sure you want to refresh?` as if it's saying the form is being worked on, but I haven't pressed submit and yet still get emails.

Answer (score 0):

This is property of your browser, after submitting `<FORM>` for first time, every time you will refresh same request will be send.

Why? As your next page is result of what you did in previous page, check your url on browser being changed to `localhost:3000/contact`, this is not a `GET` method, but a post, this has occurred as you have rendered a page on `POST` call. Even though if a different `ejs` would have rendered, on `refresh` same call to `POST: contact` would have been send.

Only solution is to use `single-page application`.

Example

`server.js`:

```

```
var express = require('express'),
path = require('path'),
nodeMailer = require('nodemailer'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var port = 3000;
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});

app.post('/contact', function (req, res) {
  let transporter = nodeMailer.createTransport({
      host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
      port: 465,
      secure: true,
      auth: {
          user: '****@gmail.com',
          pass: '****'
      }
  });
  let mailOptions = {
      from: req.body.name + ' &lt;' + req.body.email + '&gt;', // sender address
      to: '****@gmail.com', // list of receivers
      subject: 'New message test', // Subject line
      text: `${req.body.name} (${req.body.email}) says: ${req.body.message}`, // plain text body
      html: '<b>Email Test</b>' // html body
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
      if (error) {

          // Send Response back to caller
          res.status(400).send(error);
      }
      console.log('Message %s sent: %s', info.messageId, info.response);
          res.status(200).send('Success');
      });
  });
      app.listen(port, function(){
        console.log('Server is running at port: ',port);
      });
```

`

HTML/EJS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">    
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/app.css" />
        <link rel="icon" href="logo.jpg" />
        <title>Send Mail</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">

            <!-- No need for `form` as will use JavaScript for Single Page Application -->
            <div id="sendMail" class="hide">
                <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email:</label>
                    <input id="email" class="form-control" type="email">
                    <span id="emailError" class="hide error">Valid Email Required</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                    <label for="name">First Name:</label>
                    <input id="name" class="form-control" type="text">
                    <span id="nameError" class="hide error">Valid First Name Required</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                    <label for="message">Message :</label>
                    <textarea id="message" class="form-control" type="text"></textarea>
                    <span id="meggageError" class="hide error">Valid Last Name Required</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                    <p class="btn btn-primary form-control" onclick="sendMail()">Submit</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- `login.js` is only used in `login.ejs` -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/sendMail.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/service.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

`sendMail.js`:

```
"use strict";

function sendMail() {
    // JavaScript uses `id` to fetch value
    let email               = $("#email").val(),
        name                = $("#name").val(),
        message             = $("#addLname").val();

    // Show error `span` when email is invalid
    if ( validateEmail(email) ) {
        $("#emailError").addClass("hide");
    } else {
        $("#emailError").removeClass("hide");
        return;
    }

    // Show error `span` when First Name is invalid
    if ( validateFname(fName) ) {
        $("#nameError").addClass("hide");
    } else {
        $("#nameError").removeClass("hide");
        return;
    }

    // Show error `span` when Last Name is invalid
    if ( message ) {
        $("#messageError").addClass("hide");
    } else {
        $("#messageError").removeClass("hide");
        return;
    }

    // Calling local API to set authentication
    // Everything in public is visible for hackers
    // Thus to hide auth calling local backend
    $.ajax({
        "url": "/contact",
        "method": "POST",
        "data": {email, name, message}
    })
    .then( result => {
        // On success empty all the input fields.
        $("#email").val('');
        $("#name").val('');
        $("#message").val('');

        // Message to notify success submition
        alert("Successfully Send Mail.");
        return;
    })
    .catch( err => {
        // Notify in case some error occured
        alert("An error occured.");
        return;
    });
}
```

`service.js`:

```
"use strict";

/**
 * Common services used by all the other scripts
 * All these are generic functions
 *  
*/

// Validate Email based upon pattern
function validateEmail (email) {
    if ( email && email.match(/^([A-Za-z0-9]{2,})([@]{1})([A-z]{1,})([.]{1})([A-z.]{1,})*$/) ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// Validate First Name based upon pattern
function validateName (name) {
    if ( name && name.match(/^([A-Za-z]{2,})*$/) ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```